# jQuery using outside variables inside a callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ok this is what I have until know:

```
function validate() {
var validated = true;

$('.alert-infobox').fadeIn("fast", function(){
   $('input.offer').each(function(){
       // do ajax code with async = false for each input for validate if something happens
       validate = false;
   });
});

}

if(validated){
   //do something
}

return validated;
```

Now what im trying to do is to fade in and after the fade in run for each input an ajax call to verify an input in server side, now the variable validated always stay true, I believe the instruction inside the callback in the fadeIn is in different scope, is there a way to access the variable outside the callback function ?

Sorry kind of  new here :)

Thanks

Comment: Scope is not the issue, rather that fadeIn is asynchronous and returns before validate is modified.

Comment: i see typo there `validate**d**`

Comment: Although scope is issue as well as he's trying to call `validated` outside the function. I don't know how to help you here as I'm not sure exactly what you need this `validated` variable for.

Comment: What's the purpose of using ajax if you don't do it asynchronously? Do the logic inside the callback. Plus you wouldn't validate inputs one by one with ajax (making many many requests...), you'd validate on the front end and then make one single ajax request to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Within the `validate` function it's not a different scope. The callback will be ran after your if-statement.

Try the following debugging code:

```
function validate() {
    var validated = true;
    console.log("Before fadeIn");
    $('.alert-infobox').fadeIn("fast", function(){
       console.log("Callback!");
       $('input.offer').each(function(){
           // do ajax code with async = false for each input for validate if something happens
           validated = false;
       });
    });
    console.log("After fadeIn");
}

validate();
```

You will get the output in the following order:

`Before fadeIn`

`After fadeIn`

`Callback!`

Why? Because the callback is called after the animation is done, which is after about 200+ ms.

Comment: "Try some debugging code" is _such_ a general & basic comment, yet so many of these PHP and Javascript users don't do this?  Basic programming techniques, people.

Comment: Ok ;) but how do I wait for the callback to have run so I can use it before the fade in ?